# Vue.js and vue-i18n, json from $ajax to object literals

Tags: javascript, ajax, internationalization, vue.js

I am using Vue.js with the plugin [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) for internationalization purposes. It accepts a `lang` and a `locales` parameters, the later being a list of property names and associated values (`object literals`). As such, referencing an `object literals` list, either directly in the `locales` option or stored in a local variable works as expected, such as in the example below:

```
var locales = {
    "en": {
        "menu": {
            "about": "about",
            "news": "news",
            "contact": "contact"
        }
    },
    "fr": {
        "menu": {
            "about": "à propos",
            "news": "actualités",
            "contact": "contacter"
        }
    }
}

Vue.use(VueI18n, {
    lang: 'fr',
    locales: locales
});
```

Please note that despite the formatting (the double quotes all the way through the list), the above is not a `json array`, but an `object literals` list with [`string literals`for the name of the properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_Literals).

Now, what I've been struggling about is to relying on a Json file instead of declaring an `object literals` list directly in my script. For instance, I've tried an ajax request, such as this:

```
Vue.use(VueI18n, {
    lang: 'fr',
    locales: $.ajax({
                 url: "../resources/i18n/locales.json",
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "GET",
                 success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                 }
             })
});
```

The `url` string is pointing at a `locales.json` file with the exact same data and formatting as above, with the only difference that it is written inside square brackets.

I haven't had much success with this approach though, which in my mind doesn't make a lot of sense since `data` seems to be correctly parsed. This is what I get in the console:

```
Array[1]
  0: Object
    en: Object
      menu: Object
        about: "about"
        contact: "contact"
        news: "news"
    fr: Object
      menu: Object
        about: "à propos"
        contact: "contacter"
        news: "actualités"
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` returns an `xmlHttpRequest` object, not a value.  You have to wait until the callback function of `ajax` before the value is available:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../resources/i18n/locales.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        Vue.use(VueI18n, {
            lang: 'fr',
            locales: data
        });
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

This also assumes that Vue is available globally

Comment: thanks for reminding me of the need to wait for the request to succeed and the callback to be available. I do get several `[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression $t("news.message2")` warnings now (the expression obviously changes). The `data` seems to not be available, could it be that I need to iterate through it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
// install the plugin
Vue.use(VueI18n)

// load the `fr` locale dynamically
Vue.locale('fr',
  function () {
    // should return a promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      $.ajax('../resources/i18n/locales.json').done(resolve).fail(reject)
    })
  },
  function () {
    vue.config.lang = lang
  }
)
```